# Change date format dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

am working in SQL Server 2008, while merging I got error like

> conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

```
select *
from table_name
where cast(f_datetime as date) <=
cast(cast(datepart(year,cast(convert(varchar(250),@Year,103) as date)  )as varchar(250))+ '-'+ cast(datepart(MM,cast(convert(varchar(10),@month,103) as varchar(50))+'-01' as date)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why is `f_datetime` not stored as date?

Comment: Please provide example values of `f_datetime`.

Comment: Remove the dashes and use format like 20181231. 2018-02-01 can be interpreted as January 2nd or February 1st depending on the current locale and settings, while without dashes it is always YYYYMMDD. Also this casting is awful. I can't even figure out what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What are the data types of `f_datetime`, `@Year` and `@Month`?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak to the `cast()` on `f_datetime`.  But for the rest, you can do:

```
where cast(f_datetime as date) <= convert(date, convert(varchar(250), @year * 10000 + @month * 100 + 1))
```

This simplifies the calculation, and prevents things like `@year` from being treated as a `date` due to the `convert()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your f_datetime field format is "dd/mm/yyyy". If yes you can easily convert this field instead of trying to merge and convert @year and @month fields. check this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,f_datetime,103)<= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @year) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @month) + '-' + '01' AS DATE)
```